# How to detect that changing activity rotation is not possilbe in some android devices?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-tv, android-orientation

I am working on an android app that is used on both Android mobile and Android TV devices. I have a portrait activity. It works well on normal mobile but on Android Tv devices, it shows a rotated portrait screen in landscape mode. So, is there any way to force the activity to be in portrait mode? If it's not possible, how can I detect that the device does not support different orientations?

P/s: I did add this `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the AndroidManifest file.

[image]

Comment: You may try `canDetectOrientation()` from `OrientationEventListener`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener#public-methods_1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below line each activity tag of yours in your Android manifest file

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: I did it. You can see it in the image above. It's the portrait view inside a landscape screen.

Comment: How is your view rendered when you select TV for Preview for your Activity XML

Answer (score 0):

You should not run an activity in portrait mode on the TV. That goes against the [TV-LO quality requirement](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tv-app-quality#ux) and your app submission will be rejected if you submit to Google Play like that. On top of that, overscan will cut off part of your layout on some displays, so the user experience will not be good.

I'd recommend creating a landscape layout or optimizing your portrait layout to work in landscape mode. Even without TV, you're going to run into user experience issues forcing an orientation (e.g., on a tablet that's in landscape mode because a keyboard is connected).